# Connecting a class with a dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a class to a dictionary, but when i try to write it to a console it only writes:

> [1, DictionaryTest.Program+book]

I want it to write:

> [1, Michael, The book]

This is the main where i create the dictionary and try to display it on console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int,book> books = new Dictionary<int, book>();

        var book1 = new book("Michael","The Book"); 


        books.Add(1,book1);

        foreach(KeyValuePair<int,book> b in books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }

    }
```

And this is the class "book" with my two strings

```
public class book
    {
        private string Author;
        private string Title;

        public book(string Author, string Title)
        {
            this.Author = Author;
            this.Title = Title;
        }
    }
```

Hope you can help 
- Michael

Comment: Note: you  need to pay attention to conventions.  Classes should be named with UpperCamelCase and fields (like your author and title) should be named with lowerCamelCase or with _lowerCamelCase.  I'd recommend making your fields into publicly-accessible auto properties like `public string Author { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite method [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) of your class

> When you create a custom class or struct, you should override the
>   ToString method in order to provide information about your type to
>   client code.

If you don't do that, .NET doesn't know which properties to display and it will show the name of the class by default

```
public class book
    {
        public override string ToString(){
           return $"{Author} , {Title}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make `Author` and `Title` public, then you will be able to format your output in this way:

```
Console.WriteLine($"[{b.Key}, {b.Value.Author}, {b.Value.Title}]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thierry V's answer is the way to go.  A class won't just print itself, it needs to know *what* to print when you need it as a string.

Another option would be to make your `Author` and `Title` properties public and use the properties of your `Book` instance, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{b.Key}, {b.Value.Author}, {b.Value.Title}");
```

Comment: Autor is not accessible due to the protection level, Its private variable

Comment: @sujithkarivelil -- Well, that could certainly be changed, right?  It seems reasonable that there'd be accessible properties on `Book`.

Comment: Why not a public method to get those private values?

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: C# has a support for auto-properties that were designed for removing the hassle of creating public methods for accessing private properties.

Comment: It would be crazy to make methods to access private fields.  That's what properties are for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the ToString method.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, book> books = new Dictionary<int, book>();

        var book1 = new book("Michael", "The Book");


        books.Add(1, book1);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, book> b in books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
    }
}
public class book
{
    private string Author;
    private string Title;

    public book(string Author, string Title)
    {
        this.Author = Author;
        this.Title = Title;
    }

    //Overriding the ToString method.
    override
    public String ToString()
    {
        return Author + " , " + Title;
    }
}
```